# PubsubIO.readStrings() throwing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in Apache Beam v2.0.0

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam

The code below is where the exception is being thrown:

```
PCollection<String> pCol = pBegin
            .apply(String.format("Read from %s", this.subscriptionId),
                    PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription(this.subscriptionId));
```

This is the exception being thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubClient$SubscriptionPath.<init>(PubsubClient.java:188)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubClient.subscriptionPathFromName(PubsubClient.java:238)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO$SubscriptionPathTranslator.apply(PubsubIO.java:289)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO$SubscriptionPathTranslator.apply(PubsubIO.java:284)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider$NestedValueProvider.get(ValueProvider.java:131)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubUnboundedSource.getSubscription(PubsubUnboundedSource.java:1374)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubUnboundedSource$PubsubSource.<init>(PubsubUnboundedSource.java:1103)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubUnboundedSource.expand(PubsubUnboundedSource.java:1407)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubUnboundedSource.expand(PubsubUnboundedSource.java:110)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:482)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:422)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PBegin.apply(PBegin.java:44)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO$Read.expand(PubsubIO.java:730)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO$Read.expand(PubsubIO.java:536)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:482)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:441)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PBegin.apply(PBegin.java:56)
        at com.arquivei.internal.pipelines.NfeViewPipeline.buildPipeline(NfeViewPipeline.java:128)
        at com.arquivei.internal.common.base.PubSubPipeline.buildPipeline(PubSubPipeline.java:33)
        at com.arquivei.internal.ExecutePipeline$1.expand(ExecutePipeline.java:30)
        at com.arquivei.internal.ExecutePipeline$1.expand(ExecutePipeline.java:26)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:482)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:441)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PBegin.apply(PBegin.java:56)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.apply(Pipeline.java:179)
        at com.arquivei.internal.ExecutePipeline.addPipelineAsSubTask(ExecutePipeline.java:26)
        at com.arquivei.internal.ExecutePipeline.main(ExecutePipeline.java:118)
        ... 6 more
```

I've double checked the this.subscriptionId and it's not empty and follows the pattern projects/project_id/subscriptions/subscription_name

How can I resolve this problem? Any resource with a code example of reading from Pubsub subscription using Beam 2.0.0 will be also appreciated.

The project's pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <beam.version>2.0.0</beam.version>
    <google.cloud.version>0.18.0-alpha</google.cloud.version>
    <dataflow.version>2.0.0-beta2</dataflow.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>apache.snapshots</id>
        <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>all</parallel>
                <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--
              Configures `mvn package` to produce a bundled jar ("fat jar") for runners
              that require this for job submission to a cluster.
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}-bundled-${project.version}</finalName>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>

                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>config/project.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Adds a dependency on the Beam SDK. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Adds a dependency on the Beam Google Cloud Platform IO module. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The DirectRunner is needed for unit tests. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-core-java</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud</artifactId>
        <version>${google.cloud.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependencies below this line are specific dependencies needed by the examples code. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.22.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
                 in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId>
        <version>v2-rev295-1.22.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
                 in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.22.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
                 in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-pubsub</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev10-1.22.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
                 in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Add slf4j API frontend binding with JUL backend -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.14</version>
        <!-- When loaded at runtime this will wire up slf4j to the JUL backend -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hamcrest and JUnit are required dependencies of PAssert,
         which is used in the main code of DebuggingWordCount example. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-b03</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

**Solution:** Changing the Guava version from 19 to 20 solved the problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I think that this is a dependency issue with the mvn build. Would you mind providing the full pom.xml file?

Comment: @AlexAmato I've attached the project's pom.xml file in the question. Thank you!

Comment: Would you please consider trying to change com.google.guava to version 20 and see if this helps?

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: "mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose" is the best tool to figure out which version of what dependency is actually being used.

Comment: @AlexAmato Thank you! Changing guava version from 19 to 20 solved the problem. Thanks :)